# data computation in google app engine flex

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have a project where 2 datasets(kinds) are stored in google datastore having 1.1 million records together. We are also planning to add more datasets moving forward. Now we are thinking to move to app engine flex so that statistical libraries such as numpy, pandas and ML framework Scikit-learn can be utilized to build predictive models. As part of data transformation/computation pandas and numpy  will be used to extract new features out of the datasets stored in the google datastore.

Question - what is the effective approach to execute the computation logic on large datasets which involves data aggregation and transformation in the google app engine flex environment. Initial i was thinking of using task queue to do this heavy duty transformation considering it has 10 min timeout but not sure if that is feasible in flex environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that task queues have limited support in the flex environment. From [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating):

> Task Queue
>
> The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the
>   standard environment. If you want to use the service outside of the
>   standard environment, you can sign up for the [Cloud Tasks alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).
>
> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to [push
>   queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues), but a service running in the flexible environment can be
>   the target of a push task. You can specify this using the
>   [`target`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) parameter when adding a task to queue or by specifying
>   the default `target` for the queue in [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref).
>
> In many cases where you might use pull queues, such as queuing up
>   tasks or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate
>   workers, [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) can be a good alternative as it offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

One approach is already mentioned in the above quote: using **Cloud Pub/Sub**.

Another approach is also hinted at in the quote:

- keep part of the existing app as a standard env service/module, populating the datasets and pushing processing tasks into push task queues
- use the flex environment in the processing service(s)/module(s) where you need to use those libraries. These would be specified as targets for those pushed tasks.

Comment: Basically i need to read the data stored in big query or datastore and use pandas to do transformation and stored it back in new entity for further machine learning algorithm .

Comment: May be cron job  will do what i want?. it seems we can use them in app engine flex https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml

Comment: cron jobs are OK too, if your app doesn't need event-triggered processing (i.e. the logic equivalent to creating push queue tasks)  or if that can be emulated, say through periodic/scheduled polling for example.

Comment: my only concern  is processing time with cron jobs in flex environment. i am visualizing the cron job will trigger http get request method which shall contain the code to read the large data from the either bigquery or data store and perform data transformation. In the link below they mentioned the http request can run up to 60 mins. Is cron job way to go?. Can we extend the time limit beyond 60 mins?.https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml

Comment: IMHO 60 mins is A LOT. If you can't split your computation into smaller chunks you have a scalability problem, using GAE might not be the best approach, GCE may be better.